# Manager IP Helper Functions in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ip, pinvoke, unmanaged

Can any one give any managed ip helper functions converted in c#.net? I know it should be written by `PInvoke`ing.

Here is the IP Helper Functions : [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Will be grateful to you.

Here is an example:

```
public static TcpTable GetExtendedTcpTable(bool sorted)
    {
        List<TcpRow> tcpRows = new List<TcpRow>();

        IntPtr tcpTable = IntPtr.Zero;
        int tcpTableLength = 0;

        if (IpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, ref tcpTableLength, sorted, IpHelper.AfInet, IpHelper.TcpTableType.OwnerPidAll, 0) != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpTable = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(tcpTableLength);
                if (IpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable, ref tcpTableLength, true, IpHelper.AfInet, IpHelper.TcpTableType.OwnerPidAll, 0) == 0)
                {
                    IpHelper.TcpTable table = (IpHelper.TcpTable)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcpTable, typeof(IpHelper.TcpTable));

                    IntPtr rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tcpTable + Marshal.SizeOf(table.length));
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i)
                    {
                        tcpRows.Add(new TcpRow((IpHelper.TcpRow)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rowPtr, typeof(IpHelper.TcpRow))));
                        rowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)rowPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IpHelper.TcpRow)));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tcpTable != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcpTable);
                }
            }
        }

        return new TcpTable(tcpRows);
    }
```

`

and here is the native function:

```
[DllImport(IpHelper.DllName, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr tcpTable, ref int tcpTableLength, bool sort, int ipVersion, TcpTableType tcpTableType, int reserved);
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a sendmetehcodez question.  You cannot reasonably expect an SO user to give you a complete list of pinvoke declarations.  That's already been done anyway, use the pinvoke interop assistant or a site like pinvoke.net.  And of course, use the .NET framework first.  It already wraps a lot of these winapi functions, including GetExtendedTcpTable.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry. I'll try to write it on my own. Can you please guide me where .NET has wrapped up this winapi like GetExtendedTcpTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable) for that

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int GetAdaptersInfo(IntPtr pAdapterInfo, ref Int64 pBufOutLen);

[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable, ref int dwOutBufLen, bool sort, int ipVersion, TCP_TABLE_CLASS tblClass,int reserved);
```

Comment: Yeah! I know but that doesn't provide the helper functions just as I have given an example above. I mean you have to make native calls(?) again! I don't know if I am comprehensible or not!!

Comment: The helper in your sample 'deserialize' the RAW in-memory datastructures to managed objects and it obeys the WIN32 API rules for freeing memory. I think it is more wise to ask a specific question for a specific struct after you put already some effort in

Comment: Actually I am not getting how they are calling this native functions from C# and managing them. `Marshal` and all!